# Cut corners off rectangle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to reproduce [this image](http://www.sbgn.org/Symbols/complex) using TikZ. The element X can be made simply using a rectangle and the "rounded corners" attribute. But EPN instead has its corners cut off (to form an octagon). Are there any simple commands like rounded corners to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The shape `chamfered rectangle` already exists in the `shapes.misc` library:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red,chamfered rectangle,fill=red!30]
  {some text}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And some code for the image attached:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,fit,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
\node[draw,rounded corners,minimum size=1cm] 
  (x) {X};
\node[draw,circle,below=2pt of x,minimum size=1cm]
  (y) {Y};
\coordinate (aux) at ([xshift=-60pt]x);    
\node[draw=red,chamfered rectangle,fit={(aux) (x) (y)}]
  {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's some code for the other component of the image, using the fit library and some layers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,fit,positioning}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  common/.style={
    draw,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=yellow!30,
    },
  cal/.style={
    common,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=1.2cm
  },  
  ca/.style={
    common,
    circle,
    minimum height=1.2cm
  },
  conn/.style={
    draw,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=green!70!black
  },
  frame/.style={
    common,
    draw=red,
    chamfered rectangle
  },
  >=latex  
]
\node[cal] 
  (call) {Calmodulin};
\node[conn,right=of call]
  (gcon) {};
\coordinate[right=of gcon] (aux);
\node[cal,right=of aux] 
  (calr) {Calmodulin};
\node[ca,above=1.5cm of calr.east,anchor=east] 
  (car) {\ce{Ca^{2+}}};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[frame,fit={(aux) (calr) (car)}]
  (frame) {}; 
\end{pgfonlayer}
\node[ca,above right=1cm and -10pt of call] 
  (cal) {\ce{Ca^{2+}}};
\draw[->]
  (gcon) -- (call);  
\draw[->]
  (gcon) -- (frame.west|-calr.west);  
\draw[->]
  (gcon) to[bend left] (cal.south);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `pic`s could simplify the code.

Comment: Aside from everything else, thanks for introducing me to the word "[chamfer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chamfer)".